# I should create a method that accepts a character and object

Tags: java

So I should create this method that will accept a character and an object as a parameter. Then set the correct attribute to the parameter.

```
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private char gender;
    private int yob;
    private char status;
    private Person parent;

    public Person(char gender, int yob)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.yob = yob;
    }
    public void setParent(char P,Person parent)
    {
        this.parent = ();
    }
}
```

So I think they want me to set whether the parent is a 'M' for Mother or 'F' for Father. I am not sure how I am suppose to add these parameters to complete this method to accomplish that. Can anyone tell me what I would do right here?

Comment: Just a hint: normally a person has two parents.  I think you were supposed to figure that out and program your method accordingly.

Comment: @markspace I get that but I think they want me to take the character as a parameter and set the person object which is a parent to a mother or father. I get that, just not sure how to put it together.

Comment: They probably want you to set `this.mother = parent` if the character is `M` and `this.father` if it is `F`... IF

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper I think you are right, you know how I would do that though?

Comment: what is is yob?

Comment: @Bashir birth year

Comment: If you really don't understand how to do this, you need to ask your instructor.  We've given you enough clues.  If you're still missing the idea, talk to your instructor because something is wrong, either the instructor didn't teach an important concept or your note taking or attendance is affecting your comprehension.

Answer (score -1):

What it sounds like is that your assignment wants you to create a **constructor**, not a method.

```java
public void Person(char gender, Person parent) {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying and I already added all of those methods. I just showed the method I am trying to complete at the moment.

Comment: but this says that this method should take a character and the object not just the object.

Comment: Edited,my bad. Sounds more like you need a constructor